# Computing state data with reselect

Tags: javascript, react-redux, reselect

A branch of the redux state of my React web app is structured as follows:

```
  a: {
    daily: {
      offers: {
        total: 0,
        data: []
      },
      typ: {
        total: 0,
        data: []
      }
    },
    monthly: {
      offers: {
        total: 0,
        data: []
      },
      typ: {
        total: 0,
        data: []
      }
    }
  },
  b: same structure, c:same structure and so on
```

This whole state is updated with a single action, called by different functions (about 10 functions that run asynchronously) that fetch data every 30 seconds and pass it as a payload (along with the information about what to update, e.g. b.daily.offers).
The action creates a new copy of the whole state tree every time is called as by redux guidelines.

I have then a component that shows a number, as a computation of this state's totals (i pass props like ["a","b"], "monthly", "offers" to the component, to retrieve the sum of the monthly offers total)
This uses reselect as follows:

```
import {createSelector} from 'reselect'

const getGroup= (_, props) => {
  switch (props.group) {
    case "all":
      return ["a", "b", "c"];
    default:
      return props.group;
  }
};
const getTimespan = (_, props) => {
  switch (props.timespan) {
    case "daily":
      return ["daily"];
    case "monthly":
      return ["daily", "monthly"];
  }
};
const getPage = (_, props) => props.page;
const getA = (state) => state.a;
const getC = (state) => state.b;
const getB = (state) => state.c;

export const makeGetStatistic = () => {
  return createSelector(
    [getA, getB, getC, getPage, getGroup, getTimespan],
    (a, b, c, page, group, timespan) => {
      let o = 0;
      let data = {
        "a": a,
        "b": b,
        "c": c
      };
      group.forEach((device) => {
        timespan.forEach((time) => {
          o += data[device][time][page].total;
        })
      })
      return {data: o}
    });
};
```

As background functions increase in number (and they will increase, as in the future I will need to fetch more data), these selectors get called a lot, and the webapp is starting to feel more and more "slow".
Is there a way to optimize this selector? (and the actions/state tree?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see here is that `getGroup` and `getTimespan` always **return a new array**, invalidating `makeGetStatistic` selector cache on any single call.

This happens because `reselect` cache performs a strict equality comparison (`===`) check between new and previously passed values, and JS compares objects/arrays by reference.

If you want to keep both getters returning an array, you'd need to **make sure they return the same array when called with same input**. Something like:

```
const ALL_GROUPS = ["a", "b", "c"];
const getGroup= (_, props) => {
  switch (props.group) {
    case "all":
      return ALL_GROUPS;
    default:
      return props.group;
  }
};

const DAILY_TIMESPAN = ["daily"];
const MONTHLY_TIMESPAN = ["daily", "monthly"];
const getTimespan = (_, props) => {
  switch (props.timespan) {
    case "daily":
      return DAILY_TIMESPAN;
    case "monthly":
      return MONTHLY_TIMESPAN;
  }
};
```

That way `reselect` should be able to provide at least an initial level of data memoization, when called with same inputs.